# Faster evaluation of function of multiple derivatives in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a generic symbolic function x(t) [think of t as time], and a function of various derivatives of x, ie F(x(t),x'(t),x''(t),..., x^(n)(t)). I would like to evaluate F as fast as possible given numerical values for x(t),x'(t),x''(t),..., x^(n)(t). (I have a problem where I need to evaluate F a bazillion times). Here is a minimum working example of my setup:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

# setup function x
t = sp.Symbol("t")
x= sp.Matrix([sp.Function("x0")(t),
              sp.Function("x1")(t)])

def serial_derivs_xt(x,t,order):
    dim = x.shape[0]
    genx= sp.zeros(dim,order) #initialise serial time derivatives of x for each order and dimension (starting with order 0)
    for d in range(dim):
        for o in range(order):
            genx[d,o]=sp.diff(x[d], (t,o)) #o-th time derivative of the d-th component of the function x(t)
    return genx

# serial derivatives of x
genx=serial_derivs_xt(x,t,3)

#example of function F
F= sp.Matrix([genx[0,1]-genx[1,2]*genx[0,2],
              genx[0,0]-genx[0,2]*genx[1,2]+1])
```

**The problem**: I would like to evaluate F as fast as possible, given an array of numerical values for x(t),x'(t),x''(t),..., x^(n)(t). Here are two attempts I tried based on the sympy documentation: the first one works but is horribly slow, and the second one ought to be much faster but produces an error. Is there a way to obtain the output of the first method faster?

```
#Problem: evaluate F at argenx, where argenx are numeric values for genx
argenx=np.random.rand(2,3)

#Attempt 1: (works!)
def eval(F,genx,argenx):
    [dim, order] = genx.shape
    for o in reversed(range(order)):
        for d in range(dim):
            F = F.subs(genx[d, o], argenx[d, o])
    return np.array(F).astype(np.float64)
F_eval=eval(F,genx,argenx)

#Attempt 2: (Produces an error!)
F_lambdify = sp.lambdify(genx, F ,"numpy")
F_eval = F_lambdify(argenx) #ERROR
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does "produces an error" mean?

Comment: `sympy` and 'fast' don't belong in the same question. Speed is a valid concern when doing numeric work with numpy, scipy and/or numba.

Comment: Sure but sometimes symbolic computation is needed, and in my case, the slowness is an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a copy-n-paste, and looking at the variables:

```
In [2]: F
Out[2]: 
Matrix([
[Derivative(x0(t), t) - Derivative(x0(t), (t, 2))*Derivative(x1(t), (t, 2))],
[           x0(t) - Derivative(x0(t), (t, 2))*Derivative(x1(t), (t, 2)) + 1]])
```

The subs approach:

```
In [3]: #Problem: evaluate F at argenx, where argenx are numeric values for genx
   ...: argenx=np.random.rand(2,3)
   ...: 
   ...: #Attempt 1: (works!)
   ...: def eval(F,genx,argenx):
   ...:     [dim, order] = genx.shape
   ...:     for o in reversed(range(order)):
   ...:         for d in range(dim):
   ...:             F = F.subs(genx[d, o], argenx[d, o])
   ...:     return np.array(F).astype(np.float64)
   ...: F_eval=eval(F,genx,argenx)

In [4]: F_eval
Out[4]: 
array([[0.71447856],
       [1.45536036]])
```

The lambdify - the help to see what was generated:

```
In [5]: F_lambdify = sp.lambdify(genx, F ,"numpy")

In [6]: help(F_lambdify)
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(_Dummy_27, _Dummy_25, _Dummy_23, _Dummy_26, _Dummy_24, _Dummy_22)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x0, arg_1, arg_2, x1, arg_4, arg_5)
    
    Expression:
    
    Matrix([[Derivative(x0(t), t) - Derivative(x0(t), (t, 2))*Derivative(x1(t),...
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(_Dummy_27, _Dummy_25, _Dummy_23, _Dummy_26, _Dummy_24, _Dummy_22):
        return array([[-_Dummy_22*_Dummy_23 + _Dummy_25], [-_Dummy_22*_Dummy_23 + _Dummy_27 + 1]])
```

And the error - that you forget to show - or was your intention more sinsister?

```
In [7]: F_eval = F_lambdify(argenx)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 F_eval = F_lambdify(argenx)

TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 5 required positional arguments: '_Dummy_25', '_Dummy_23', '_Dummy_26', '_Dummy_24', and '_Dummy_22'
```

The lambdify expects 6 arguments, we only provided 1.  The `*` doesn't help since it only expands the (2,3) array into 2 arrays:

```
In [8]: F_eval = F_lambdify(*argenx)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 1
----> 1 F_eval = F_lambdify(*argenx)

TypeError: _lambdifygenerated() missing 4 required positional arguments: '_Dummy_23', '_Dummy_26', '_Dummy_24', and '_Dummy_22'
```

But if I flatten the array, and expand that, it works, by passing 6 numbers to the function:

```
In [9]: argenx
Out[9]: 
array([[0.4857742 , 0.7448924 , 0.19825219],
       [0.46089018, 0.93328276, 0.15340986]])

In [10]: F_eval = F_lambdify(*argenx.ravel())

In [11]: F_eval
Out[11]: 
array([[0.71447856],
       [1.45536036]])
```

I won't go into the details, but you need to pay attention to what the `lambdify` generates.  Here it's the number of arguments that matters.  Other times there are problems with the un-translated functions.  `lambdify` has only a basic understanding of `numpy`, and can be easily messed up.

### edit

It does work with a (6,n) array. Or,my guess, any 6 arrays that broadcast together, since they combine with ordinary math operators.

Comment: Thank you very much! I accepted this answer as it provides the fastest solution (2 orders of magnitude faster than my original code, after comparing with the time package).

Answer (score 1):

Unpack your `argenx` as shown below when calling:

```py
from sympy import *
...your code
argenx = randMatrix(2,3)
F_lambdify = lambdify(genx, F)  # not passing "numpy"
ok = F_lambdify(*argenx)  # (*argenx) instead of (argenx)
>>> argenx = Matrix([[0.4857742 , 0.7448924 , 0.19825219],[0.46089018, 0.93328276, 0.15340986]])
>>> F_lambdify(*argenx)
matrix(
[['0.714478559287407'],
 ['1.45536035928741']])
```